# Drawing a moving line in a transparent panel in C#

Tags: c#, drawing, transparency

There seems to be a million questions out there on this, yet I can't find one that will work. So, I guess it's time for question 1,000,001.

I have a custom control with a `PictureBox` and a `Panel`. The `Panel` is the child of `PictureBox` with a transparent background. This allows me tp draw on top of whatever image is loaded in the `PictureBox`.

The drawing part works, but the erasing part does not. And if I use `Invalidate()` I just get a bunch of flickering, and the line never even shows.

If the end goal isn't obvious, it should work like any decent drawing application, where you click in one spot, drag around, and the line moves with the mouse until you let go.

Code:

```
private void drawLine(Point pt) {
    // Erase the last line
    if (m_lastPoints != null) {
        m_graphics.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        m_graphics.DrawLine(m_transPen, m_lastPoints[0], m_lastPoints[1]);
    }

    // Set the last points
    m_lastPoints = new Point[] { m_mouseStartPoint, pt };

    m_graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(m_color), m_mouseStartPoint, pt);
}
```

`m_transPen` is defined as `new Pen(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));`

And the result:

[image]

Now, if I change it to:

```
m_graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, m_lastPoints[0], m_lastPoints[1]);
```

I get this, which shows what it should be doing, only instead of with white lines, they should be transparent.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to erase the old line! Just invalidate the `Panel` and  draw the fresh one, best in the `Paint` event.

**But** for this to work, the `Panel` **must not overlay** the `PictureBox`. It must be **inside** it! Put this in the load or constructor event :

```
yourPanel.Parent  = yourPictureBox;
yourPanel.Size = yourPictureBox.Size; 
yourPanel.Location = Point.Empty;
```

(I know you got that one right already, but maybe the next person only looks at the answer ;-)

To avoid **flicker** use a `double-buffered Panel`..:

```
class DrawPanel : Panel
{
    public DrawPanel()
    {
        DoubleBuffered =  true;
    }
}
```

..or, better yes, a `Picturebox` or a `Label` (with `Autosize=false`); both have the `DoubleBuffered` property turned on out of the box and support drawing better than `Panels` do.

**Actually**, if you only want to draw something on top of the loaded `Image`, you don't even need a separate `Panel`. Just draw on the `PictureBox` itself! It has three independent layers: `BackgroundImage`, `Image` and the `Control surface`..

Here is the minimal code to draw a Cursor controlled line:

```
pictureBox1.MouseDown += pictureBox1_MouseDown;
pictureBox1.MouseMove += pictureBox1_MouseMove;
pictureBox1.MouseUp   += pictureBox1_MouseUp;
pictureBox1.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;

// class level
Point mDown   = Point.Empty;
Point mCurrent = Point.Empty;

void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (mDown != Point.Empty) e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, mDown, mCurrent);
}

void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mDown = Point.Empty;
}

void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        mCurrent = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}

void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mDown = e.Location;
}
```

The line disappears when you release the mouse button.

To make it permanent you need to store its two points in a list of data needed to draw them and work through that list in the `Paint` event.

That list should probably also include the color, pen width and then some, so  designing a class 'drawAction' will help..

Comment: How do I use the Control surface?

Comment: __Exactly__ like you (should) use the Panel's surface! both are Controls and both can be drawn on. Best use the `Paint` event, keep the 2 points for the Line ready in class variables and Invalidate the Picturebox when they change. In the Paint event use `e.Graphics.DrawLine(..)`!

Comment: for the correct way to draw onto a Control see the example!