# Draw line on a dynamically created picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

i need to draw a line for example, in a dynamically created `PictureBox`. What happens is that the picture box is created and shown in the form but the line is missing. My code is below, any ideas?? thnx

```
public void create_pb()
{
    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.Size = new Size(200, 200);
    pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    pb.Location = new Point(0,0);
    panel1.Controls.Add(pb);
    g = pb.CreateGraphics();
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);

    g.DrawLine(p, 0, 0, 200, 200);           
}
```

`g` is defined as `public Graphics g;`

Comment: have you checked out the `Invalidate()` Method sounds like this could be the problem also here is an existing working project that can give you some ideas as well .[CodeProject Drawing on PictureBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/318900/Drawing-on-picture-box-images)

Comment: Have a look at the bottom of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403514/drawing-a-moving-line-in-a-transparent-panel-in-c-sharp/28405275#28405275), especially the setting up of the event handlers!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `CreateGraphics`. You need to do your drawing in the `Paint` event handler instead, using `e.Graphics` from the event arguments passed to you.

Otherwise your line will simply be erased when the picture box is next repainted (e.g. when the form is moved, resized, covered by another form, etc).

Example:

```
pb.Paint += (sender, e) =>
{
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 0, 0, 200, 200);
};
```