# copying free hand drawing from panel in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, picturebox

I want to draw free hand in a form (picture box) on visual studio and copy the same figure (that I draw) on another panel/picture box.
Also they should not be dots forming one line but a continuous line. Please help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Pen p_white;

        bool draw = true;

        private Graphics objgraphics;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen p_black = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black));

            if (draw)
            {
                objgraphics = panel1.CreateGraphics();

            }

        }

        /*private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            bool draw = true;
        }*/

        private void panel1_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
                      Rectangle rEllipse = new Rectangle();


            switch (e.Button)
            {

                case MouseButtons.Left:

                    rEllipse.X = e.X;
                    rEllipse.Y = e.Y;
                    rEllipse.Width = 5;
                    rEllipse.Height = 5;
                    objgraphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rEllipse);
                    break;

                case MouseButtons.Right:

                    rEllipse.X = e.X;
                    rEllipse.Y = e.Y;
                    rEllipse.Width = 3;
                    rEllipse.Height = 3;
                    objgraphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rEllipse);
                    break;

                default:
                    return;
           } 

        }

        /*private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            bool draw = false;
        } */

        private void form_Paint(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void panel2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            Pen p_black = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black));

            if (draw)
            {                objgraphics = panel1.CreateGraphics();

            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is very simple, __provided you do the the drawing right in the first place__. (Which is: storing the mouse points in the mousemove in a class level `List<Point>` ((or possible a `List<List<Point>>`)) and drawing them in the panel paint event. To copy all you need is to code the panel2's paint event to draw the same.) - But since you are new, you probably don't do it right. Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: Thank you Taw. I do. This is how I am drawing in C#. Please check the code now.

Comment: Check out the answer I wrote. I contains a __lot__ to study and to learn from, but it will be worth it..

Comment: Thanks TaW, I completed the task successfully and you have been a huge help with that detailed explanation. 
Now I need to save these drawings in a word file. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't do office automation, unfortunately.  You can create a Bitmap containing the drawing simply by using [DrawToBitMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584465/use-picturebox-as-a-canvas-and-draw-text/30600471?s=5|0.0000#30600471) but how to insert it into a word doc I don't know. There should be many examples around, though.. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your code I'm afraid I have to say: This is  **all wrong**.

Sorry to be so blunt, but you **must never use control.CreateGraphics!!**

- The first thing to do is to throw away the `Graphics objgraphics` object.

It is (almost) always wrong to store a `Graphics` object!

Instead, you have to use the one you get from the `e.Graphics` parameter in the `Paint` events of your controls.

Note that `Graphics` **doesn't contain** any graphics, it is a tool used to draw onto an associated `Bitmap` or a control's surface.

- The next thing is to do is to understand about drawing freehand lines. Often one can see the code you have; but it is useless and only an example of how many stupid things you find in introductions. Forget it. It will always look like crap as the circles simply never look smooth and as soon as you move the mouse faster the pseudo-lines completely fall apart.

There is a nice method `DrawCurve` that will draw smooth lines. You feed it a `Pen` and an array of `Points`.

This is what we will use.

Let's return to the basics: How to create a graphic? Now we know that you need to call `DrawCurve` in the `Paint` event:

```
e.Graphics.DrawCurve(somePen, somePointsArray);
```

This brings up the next questions:

- what's somePen
- what's somePointsArray

There is a hidden third question:

- what about drawing more lines?

The first one is simple; you create a `Pen` with a stroke width of 5.5 pixels as

```
Pen somePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 5.5f);
```

If you want to you can give it a linestyle (dashes), too.

Now for the array: In its simplest form this is easy as well.

In the `MouseMove` event you store the current `Location` in a list of points. First, we declare it at class level:

```
List<Point> currentLine = new List<Point>();
```

Then we start filling it as long as the left button is pressed:

```
private void panel1_MouseMove_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        currentLine.Add(e.Location);
        panel1.Invalidate();
    }  
}
```

Note the last line: Calling `Invalidate` on a control triggers the **system** to invoke the `Paint` event. It may look complicated but this is the only correct way as it guarantees that the very same drawing will also happen when some **other** reason makes it necessary.

**We** need to draw because we have changes the data that should be drawn. But there are many **outside** reasons, most notoriously the `Minimize/maximize` sequence that will clear the drawing and trigger the `Paint` event, too. So we need to **cooperate** with the way **windows** draws its controls! Only this way the graphics will **persist**.

Also, note we don't use an array as we don't know how many `Points` we will need. Instead, we use a `List` and later cast it to `Array`.

Let's code the `Paint` event for our simple case:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   using (Pen somePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 5.5f) )
     if (currentLine.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawCurve(yourPen , currentLine.ToArray());
}
```

Note that I have created the `Pen` in a `using` clause. This is a cheap and safe way to ensure that the `Pen` is disposed of properly.

Also note how we cast the `List` to an `Array`!

The above code alone would work and allow you free-hand drawing a line.

But what about the next line? It should not connect to the first one so we can't just add more points!

So we need not just **one** list of points but **more** than that, in fact, a list of lists of points is called for:

```
List<List<Point>> curves = new List<List<Point>>();
```

And we add the current curve to it whenever the mouse is released:

```
private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentLine.Count > 1) curves.Add(currentLine.ToList());  // copy!!
    currentLine.Clear();
    panel1.Invalidate();
}
```

Note how I use a cast from `List` to `List` to enforce a copy or else only the reference would be assigned and then, in the next line cleared..

Again we trigger the `Paint` event as the final thing to do.

We now should change the `Paint` event to display all the lines, both the one currently being drawn and all the earlier ones..:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Pen somePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 5.5f) )
    {
       if (currentLine.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawCurve(somePen, currentLine.ToArray());
       foreach (List<Point> lp in curves)
          if (lp.Count > 1) e.Graphics.DrawCurve(somePen, lp.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Now we are basically done with the free-hand drawing part.

So we return to your original question: How can you copy the drawing to a **second** `Panel`?

Well, you have stored everything in the `curves` data structure.

So you have two options: Either simply use the same data in the `panel2_Paint` event or if you need to copy and change the data to, maybe adapt to a different size.

Here are the things still missing:

- Saving the data, saving the drawing (`Serialize`, `DrawToBitMap`)
- Drawing with varying pens & colors (create a `drawAction` class to store all you need)
- Using other tools like Line or Rectangle (create a `drawAction` class)
- Clearing the drawing (see below)
- Undo and Redo (look into `Stacks` an `Queues`)
- Caching when there are a great number of lines ( draw the first portion into a `BackgroundImage Bitmap`)

Here is a clearing code:

```
curves.Clear(); currentLine .Clear(); panel1.Invalidate();
```

I noted that your original code lets you draw with two different stroke widths using the left and right button. This alone shows that this code is not very good. Who would a) think of that and b) be satisfied with only two stroke widths.

Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714411/update-a-drawing-without-deleting-the-previous-one/28716887?s=5%7C0.1873#28716887) where I explain a little about creating a class that can store a pen width, a color etc so that you can change then between lines you draw.