# save a panel with drawings C#

Tags: c#, image, winforms, save

For a litte project, I tryed creating a ""Paint App".

Now I want to save the painting as File, sadly, my Method will only save the Background and my menuestrip.

This is how I create the Panel and drawing method:

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)  //Bild erstellen
    {
        Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();

        Pen pen = new Pen(colorDialog1.Color);
        g.DrawEllipse(pen, pointx, pointy, width, height);
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) //Linie malen
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            pointx = e.X;
            pointy = e.Y;
            panel1_Paint(this, null);
        }
    }
```

This is how I create a Bmp:

```
        private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        save.CheckFileExists = false;
        save.CheckPathExists = true;
        save.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) | *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png";
        save.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\";

        DialogResult result = save.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);

            panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));

            bmp.Save(save.FileName);

        }
    }
```

[My output File looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD40U.png)

[What is should look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rXTX.png)

Thankful for every advice :)

Comment: _Graphics g = panel1.CreateGraphics();_ __Never__ use  this. Always use `e.Graphics`from the `Paint` parms. Also: You need to collect the locatins in a `List<Point> points` and use ` `e.Graphics.DrawLines` or `e.Graphics.DrawCurve(points.ToArray())` !

Comment: And for nicer results collect the curve in a  `List<List>Point>>`[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31988079/copying-free-hand-drawing-from-panel-in-visual-studio-2013/32112426#32112426) ! For even more advanced doodling [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290951/creating-different-brush-patterns-in-c-sharp/49298313#49298313)

Comment: So I have to rewrite my creation method :D I'll try, thanks @TaW

Comment: Well, the saveToolStripMenuItem_Click looks fine; just the others must be overhauled.

Comment: :D at least someting is right, and thanks a lot for the detailed description in your link!